# $f$ is increasing, $f(x)\not=x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(0)>0$. Prove that $f(1)>1$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f$ is increasing, $f(x)\not=x$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(0)>0$. Prove that $f(1)>1$.

**My attempt:**

Denote $S:=\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)>x\}$. It suffices to show that $\sup S\in S$.

Since $0\in S$, we have $S$ is nonempty.

Since $S$ must be bounded above by $1$, by the completeness property, $\sup S$ exists.

Let $M=\sup S$. By definition of supremum, $M\le 1$.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction, $M\notin S$. Then $f(M)\le M$.

Note that $f(x)\not=x$, we have $f(M)<M$.

With the increasing property, we have $0<f(0)\le f(M)<M\le 1$.

At this point, I am stuck. Can anyone offer any assistance? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Meitar You can't use IVT. $f$ is increasing not necessarily continuous

Comment: My apologies, I will keep the above comment just so others can pick up on that mistake, if that's okay

Comment: It is not sufficient to show $\sup S\in S$, you also need to show $\sup S=1$

Comment: If $M\notin S$, $f(M)$ is. What does it mean? Your idea is good. Try to explore it. Take a look at my answer, you can still keep your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have shown the supreme exists. Let $\sup S=M$, and you want to prove $M\in S$.

Assume $M\notin S$, then we have $f(M)<M$, let $\delta=M-f(M)>0$

Since $M$ is the supreme of $S$, so $\exists x\in S$, such that $M-\delta<x<M$

then we have $f(x)>x>M-\delta=f(M)$

Since $x<M$, but $f(x)>f(M)$, this contradicts with the fact $f$ is increasing.

Comment: Thank you. That helps!

Comment: You are welcome, but you still need to show the sup=1

Answer (score 1):

Let $m=\inf \{x, f(x)\le x\}$. If $m=0$, then for any $\epsilon$ small enough, there exists $0 \le x\le \epsilon$ such that $f(x)< x$, but since $f(0)=a>0$, that would mean there is $0\le x\le a$ with $f(x)<a$ contradicting increasing of $f$.
Hence, $m>f(0)$.

We go on by Assuming $m< 1$, in which case, either $k:=f(m)<m$, $f(k)>k$ by definition of $m$, and again it contradicts increasing of $f$, as $k<f(k)<f(m)=k$ which, because of strong inequality is impossible.

Can you expand on this idea?

Comment: Note: I was inspired by your idea and I looked at it a bit differently. I will make an attempt to see, however, how it can be done your way.

Answer (score 1):

Using your notation let $x$ such that $x \in S$ and $f(M) \le x < M$. Then

$$f(M) \ge f(x) > x \ge f(M).$$

This is a contradiction. This proves that $M\in S$